# Drag and drop notification

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I got an app in wpf which support drag and drop of items. I am looking to take certain actions when drag operation complete. If user drop the dragged item within my application I get the notification and can take required actions but if user drop the item outside my application I can't take the required actions as I can't find a way to know when user has dropped the item (at a non-dropable zone) i-e on an application which doesn't allow dropping.

Is it possible to get a notification if/when user drop the dragged item outside of app?

Regards,